# jquery form validate not allow space for field non required field?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-validate

jquery form validate not allow space for field non required field
i have tried this but is not working

```
$(document).ready(function(){

jQuery.validator.addMethod("noSpace", function(value, element) { 
 return value.indexOf(" ") < 0 && value != ""; 
   }, "No space please and don't leave it empty");


$("form").validate({
 rules: {
  name: {
      noSpace: true
  }
   }
    });


  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this much of code.

```
 jQuery.validator.addMethod("noSpace", function(value, element) { 
 return value.indexOf(" ") < 0 ; 
  }, "No space please and don't leave it empty")
```